# How do I enable h2 console in application.yml for SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have an application.yml file where I want to enable **h2-console** but on searching over google I got results only for application.properties file.  Can anyone help?

Comment: application.yml is just another way of specifying properties. Take the properties from the examples you found, and writen them in yml style. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties

Answer (score 9):

You can use below configuration.

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
```

Refer this for more : https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-rest-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml

AND

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql-h2-console

Answer (score 2):

for properties and yml use the following 
(application.yml)

```
spring:
 h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
```

(application.properties)

```
   spring.h2.console.enabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use this structure

```
###
#   H2 Settings
###
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /console
      settings:
        trace: false
        web-allow-others: false
```